# Python Pandas Histogram odd/even sorting

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, histogram

I have function that plots some hists (data is in range 1...15)

```py
    def show_hist(filename):
        df = pd.read_csv(filename, delimiter=',', header=None)
        plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))
        df[1].value_counts()[:15].plot(kind='bar')
        plt.savefig('img1.png')
        plt.clf()
        df[3].value_counts()[:15].plot(kind='bar')
        plt.savefig('img2.png')
        plt.clf()
        df[4].value_counts(sort = False).plot(kind='bar')
        plt.savefig('img3.png')
```

My question is about part with img3.png - it saves histogram with 15 bars from 1 to 15.

And sometimes when I import this function to another file in the same project or just copy the code, bars on img3 are grouped by odd/even - bars 2..4..6..8..etc at left and 1..3..5..etc on right

Why it happens? and Is there any option to make it straight again?

PS data looks like this:

```
8796,.2.3.5.7.14.15,6,.2.3,2
8797,.1.3.8.12.13.15,6,.1.3,1
8798,.9,1,.9,9
8799,.5.6.10,3,.5.6,5
8800,.3.5.12.14,4,.3.5,3
8801,.4.11.12.13,4,.4.11,4
```

[correct img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hbg3i.png)
[wrong img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Glt8i.png)

Comment: Please, provide some data and images of your figures.

Comment: Added piece of data and imgs

Comment: Why did you set `sort=False` in `df[4].value_counts(sort = False)`?

Comment: To keep 1-2-3-... sequence on X axis

Comment: What happens if you remove it? Can you post the figure here?

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/nuoI5BI.png

Comment: Uhn... what is the output of `df[4].value_counts().index`?

Comment: Int64Index([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 11, 8, 10, 9, 12, 13, 15, 14], dtype='int64') without sort option

and Int64Index([2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15], dtype='int64') with (sort = False)

Comment: Okay, so try `aux = df[4].value_counts()`, then `aux.sort_index().plot(kind='bar')`

Comment: Great, I added an answer, please accept it if it's okay for your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, you are trying to do a histogram using value_counts, and the issue here is that pandas index isn't sorted.
Please, try the following code:

```
aux = df[4].value_counts()
aux.sort_index().plot(kind='bar')
```